# What's wrong with my code here?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to get my timer to display on the screen. Whenever I run the program, I get a NullPointerException in 2 places. I commented the lines that had the errors

```
    myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(31000, 1000);
    myCountDownTimer.onTick(31000); //NullPointerException on this line
    myCountDownTimer.onFinish();
```

Here's MyCountDownTimer Class

```
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {



TextView textCounter;

    public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        textCounter.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000)); //NullPointerException on this line

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        textCounter.setText("Finished");

    }


}
```

Edit:

```
 myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(31000, 1000);
    myCountDownTimer.thisText(textCounter);
    myCountDownTimer.onTick(31000);

    myCountDownTimer.onFinish();
```

and this was added to MyCountDownTimer

```
public TextView thisText(TextView textCounter){
            return textCounter;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextView textCounter;` is null; if you created it in your activity then, create a constructor for your `MyCountDownTimer` and take `TextView` as parameter and put it in.. because if you create a `TextView` in your `MyCountDownTimer` its useless because you have to add it again to your content View..

like this

```
 public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
 TextView textCounter;

  public MyCountDownTimer(TextView textCounter, long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    this.textCounter = textCounter;
   }
// now you can use textCounter and not get an exception
```

Hope it helps

Comment: do I create the constructor in the activity or MyCountDownTimer Class?

Comment: you do it in your MyCountDownTimer class @ThatThatson

Comment: I tried this but I think i'm missing something. I added the code to my Op .

Comment: what no no, copy what i have to your MyCountDownTimer class. i wrote it for you, and you initialise it this way `new MyCountDownTimer(yourTextView,31000, 1000);` @ThatThatson

Comment: Ok I got it to work with no errors now. All I need to do is figure out how to get the timer to show 30-0 instead of just going straight to finish.

Comment: can you elaborate, show 30-0 on the textview? what does it show now@ThatThatson

Comment: I got it now. I forgot to include the start method

Comment: @Elitz would you happen to know how to send the page to a new Activity when the timer is complete?

Comment: yes Sir, i know, in your timer class you will see  `onFinish()` it will be triggered when its finished, there you can use intent to start a new activity like this `context.startActivity(new Intent(context,yournewclass.class));` that's all, if you are wondering about context is for now your activity, you can get the context, by either using the approach of the textview and pass the activity in your constructor or you could do `textCounter.getContext()` it returns the context... try the second approach first. @ThatThatson

Comment: I get a Null pointer exception here      
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Retry.class))

Comment: sir can you create a chat and invite me rather? did you use the 2nd or 1st approach? what i meant was `textCounter.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(textCounter.getContext(), retry.class));` or use constructor style and pass in your context like this `public MyCountDownTimer(Context context,TextView textCounter, long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    this.textCounter = textCounter; this.context = context` then you can use context, you need a declared context variable in your class like you did for the textview scenario@ThatThatson

Comment: I don't have enough rep to cha so I sent you an email to your rumorsapp

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your object before you use it:

```
TextView textCounter = new TextView();
```

You have one NullPointerException, they on the same command.

Comment: where do I place this?

Comment: Here an example how initialize TextView: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/textview/android-textview-example/